How to add Fall-Off texture to every instance in geometry nodes individually and keep each instances color?
In Geo Nodes I have a setup that creates these colored circles on certain points. This circles are overlapping and thus not all colors are visible right.
I have a texture with a fade/fall-off. But I can't find a way to add this fade to each individual circles.
The mix-shader node only applies the fade over all the circles and not to each individually.
The color of the circle needs to stay the same just fade towards the edge of the circle.
Is there a way to add this texture to each instance and keep the color?


Probably need to UVUnwrap the circles and then use that vector data as an input into the ImageTexture node's vector input from the attribute node in the material.

Thanks to @Jakemoyo I was able to generate the shader I needed!
I had to use an object from the scene, the white circle, that I UV unwrapped and added a mix shader with a principled and a transparent shader.


Nicely done! Remember to mark your own answer as accepted whenever you can so that the question gets removed from the "Unanswered questions" queue.
